# When dropping constraints, an index is created automatically

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to remove a foreign key constraint from a table. However, every time I drop the constraint, it would seem that an index is created afterwards.

Table `configtool_access_control` constraints:

```
CONSTRAINT FK_configtool_access_control_configtool_app_site_app_site_id FOREIGN KEY (app_site_id)
  REFERENCES configtool_app_site (app_site_id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
```

Drop statement:

```
use my_db;

set AUTOCOMMIT=1;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
flush privileges;

alter table configtool_access_control
  drop FOREIGN KEY FK_configtool_access_control_configtool_app_site_app_site_id;
```

Resulting index is created in table `configtool_access_control`:

```
INDEX FK_configtool_access_control_configtool_app_site_app_site_id (app_site_id)
```

Does that mean that I have to script the removal of the index at the same time? Is there a way to drop both at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're creating [FOREIGN KEY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html), DBMS will create the corresponding key too . To say short, `'foreign key' = 'usual key' + 'foreign constraint'`. So, when you're dropping only constraint, your key will still persists - so you'll need to drop it too if you really need to do that.

To understand that better, execute `SHOW INDEXES` syntax on your table after creating foreign key - then you'll see that you have the corresponding 'usual' key.

Comment: @alma-do-mudo so, for each foreign key drop, an according index drop is needed?